# JavaFX graphicsContext.drawimage() outofmemory error

Tags: java, javafx

It's gonna be my first post here, so any suggestions are welcome.

Problem with growing amount of memory is with this piece of code

```
private void drawChart(Canvas canvas) {
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    Img i = getRecentImage(); // it contains byte[] source (png format). Img is my own class
    Image i = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(i.getImageBytes()););
    gc.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
}
```

And now what happens. After a while, after loading hundreds of these images (they are like 100KB each uncompressed) program crashes with outofmemory error.

When i add

```
gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

just before

```
gc.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
```

everything works fine.

Problem with that piece of code is that i don't understand why clearing region (making it blank) makes no memory leak. Does drawImage() method keep references to my objects (byte[] arrays) somewhere, until they are cleared by gc.clearRect(), or.. ? I thought that i just copy-paste byte[] buffer so i operate on same gc memory all the time.

Comment: Is the canvas attached to the scenegraph and visible on screen?

Comment: @mipa yes, it's drawn on scene all the time. I push data (drawChart()) through Platform.runLater(task)

Comment: According to docs [`GraphicsContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) uses Canvas buffer. And according to source code `drawImage()` puts the image and some params to this buffer. However it is not clear why buffer is not flushed automatically. Maybe you are filling it faster, than it is rendered to canvas?

Comment: It is redrawn every 2-5 seconds. Looks like it keeps references based on x,y position, which it shouldn't. Kinda weird.